# Is it possible to instrument an APK file without source code?

Tags: android, instrumentation, emma

I am looking for a tool for returning the code coverage of an Android apk. All solutions I foung consider I have the source code. In this especific case I don't. I know EMMA, but it works for .jar files.

Would anyone can help me, please?

Thanks.

Comment: APKs are trivial to decompile.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, thanks for the reply. I decompiled my apk using dex2jar, by the steps: d2j-dex2jar.sh -f -o HelloAndroidWithMenus_dex2jar.jar HelloAndroidWithMenus.apk But, when I tried java -cp emma.jar emma instr -m overwrite -cp HelloAndroidWithMenus_dex2jar.jar I got the error: coud not to find or load main class emma. Would do you know how to solve it, please?

Comment: `java -cp emma.jar emma` - is the main class really named `emma`?  Seems unlikely.  Probably more like `com.something.Emma`.  Or you might be able to run it with `java -jar emma.jar`.

Comment: Try this project : https://github.com/androcoverage/androcoverage
It uses EMMA to automatically instrument applications and generate code coverage reports.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good practice but one solution would be to rename the apk file to a jar file and then use EMMA tool..